# Passing required length value automatically in angular

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I want to pass the minimum length error message automatically by adding the code bellow, but `{{username?.errors?.['minLength'].requiredLength}}` doesn't show any number!

and when I put a number instead of `{{username?.errors?.['minLength'].requiredLength}}` it shown correctly in the error message.

PS: I use angular cli 13

```
<div *ngIf="username?.errors?.['minlength']">
    **{{ username?.errors?.['minLength'].requiredLength }}** characters At least
</div>
```

Comment: it means that one of the properties you are referring is undefined. remove the "**?**" and you will find out which one.

Comment: Can you show us the typescript code? Is username a getter for that formcontrol? the html should look like this: formControl.errors.minlength.requiredLength

Comment: Typo, should be: `{{ username?.errors?.['minlength'].requiredLength }}`